# 'More hot questions' JS is broken in the new nav

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hot-questions, javascript, new-nav

When I try to click the 'more hot questions' link at the bottom of the sidebar on SO or mSE (with the new navigation), it just bumps me to the top of the page and doesn't do anything. Nothing in the error console. This only seems to affect the front page of sites, upon further testing.

Safari 9 on OS X 10.11.

Comment: Front pages don't have the "more hot questions" link as far as I can see. Maybe you have a long forgotten userscript that stopped working.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't have any userscripts running right now. On http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/new?show=all&sort=newest&pageSize=50, I see this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ehrEa.png. Do you see something different?

Comment: Yes, I get Page Not Found. It means it's part of the new navigation, which is still in test phase and probably does not support the Hot Network Questions yet.

Comment: Ah, then it's a new nav bug. Thanks @Shadow.

Comment: No repro on Opera 12 on Vista

Comment: I've been experiencing the same problem for a while now on the latest version of Safari in both Yosemite and EL Capitan.